# Erro persistente no C# banco de dados

Tags: c#, query, oledb

Estava fazendo um projeto mas apareceu um problema envolvendo OleDbCommand ocorrendo em dois lugares diferentes:

```
    dr_alu = _dataCommand.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr_alu.HasRows == true)


     dr_reg_notas = _dataCommand.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr_reg_notas.HasRows == true)
```

já tentei praticamente tudo mas não consigo achar um jeito de conserta-lo. Ficaria muito grato alguma ajuda. Obrigado.

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.ComponentModel;
        using System.Data;
        using System.Drawing;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Windows.Forms;
        using System.Data.OleDb;

        namespace ProjetoEscola
        {
        public partial class dgv_notas : Form
        {

        OleDbConnection conn = Conexao.obterConexao();

        OleDbConnection dr_alu;
        BindingSource bs_alu = new BindingSource();

        OleDbConnection dr_disc;
        BindingSource bs_disc = new BindingSource();

        OleDbConnection dr_menc;
        BindingSource bs_menc = new BindingSource();

        OleDbConnection dr_reg_notas;
        BindingSource bs_reg_notas = new BindingSource();

        String _query;

        public dgv_notas()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void carregar_aluno()
        {
            _query = "SELECT * from alunos order by nome";
            OleDbCommand _dataCommand = new OleDbCommand(_query, conn);
            dr_alu = _dataCommand.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr_alu.HasRows == true)
            {
                bs_alu.DataSource = dr_alu;
                cmb_aluno.DataSource = bs_alu;
                cmb_aluno.DisplayMember = "nome";
                cmb_aluno.ValueMember = "matricula";
                lbl_matricula.Text = cmb_aluno.SelectedValue.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Não temos Alunos Cadastrados !!!!", "Atenção", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

            }
        }

        private void carregar_grid()
        {
            _query = "SELECT Alunos.Nome, Disciplinas.sigla, Disciplinas.descricao, Registro_Mencoes.mencao FROM Disciplinas INNER JOIN (Alunos INNER JOIN Registro_Mencoes ON Alunos.Matricula = Registro_Mencoes.matricula) ON Disciplinas.cod_disciplina = Registro_Mencoes.cod_disciplina order by Alunos.Nome";

            OleDbCommand _dataCommand = new OleDbCommand(_query, conn);
            dr_reg_notas = _dataCommand.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr_reg_notas.HasRows == true)
            {
                bs_reg_notas.DataSource = dr_reg_notas;
                dgv_notas.DataSource = bs_reg_notas;

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Não temos Menções Lançadas !!!", "Atenção", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }

        }

        private void resigtro_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            carregar_grid();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Não sei por que mas o Has.Rows também é marcado

Comment: Qual a mensagem de erro

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader' to 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection'

Comment: Bom isso é tipos Você ja tentou declara assim

Comment: OleDbDataReader  Teste = _dataCommand.ExecuteReader();

Comment: bom voce esta usando um  OleDbConnection = OleDbDataReader

Comment: Nossa, não acredito que era isso! Muito obrigado amigo me ajudou demais... Nem passou por minha cabeça isso

Comment: Nada a ver com a pergunta, mas para melhorar o código, cheque sobre comparar valores booleanos no link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614839/using-or-equals-for-bool-comparison. Em resumo, isso 'if (dr_reg_notas.HasRows == true)' é mais devagar que isso 'if (dr_reg_notas.HasRows)'

Answer (score 3):

Você esta usando objeto `OleDbConnection` para receber uma objeto `OleDbDataReader`, por isso o erro

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader' to
>   'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection'

```
 OleDbCommand _dataCommand = new OleDbCommand(_query, conn);
 OleDbDataReader varavelReader = _dataCommand.ExecuteReader();
 if (varavelReader.HasRows == true)
{
   ....
}
```

Como pode ser Observado no exemplo abaixo retirado do site da documentação [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/979byfca(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public void CreateReader(string connectionString, string queryString)
{
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString());
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, era isso mesmo! Nem tinha pensado nisso. Obrigado!

Comment: @Matheus A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o tour se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você declarou as variáveis `dr_reg_notas` e `dr_alu` como variáveis `OleDbConnection` e está tentando usa-las como variáveis `OleDbDataReader`.

O certo a fazer seria criar outra variável:

```
OleDbCommand _dataCommand = new OleDbCommand(_query, conn);
var leitor = _dataCommand.ExecuteReader();
if (leitor.HasRows == true)
{
}
```